# Android Studio Java plugin error

Tags: android-studio, updates, beta

I just upgraded my Android Studio to the very latest version 1.0rc4 and i am getting this error in gradle sync window
[image: The error]
What is it I am supposed to do to make the build successful?

Comment: Update Java JDK maybe?

Comment: Can you include your app build.gradle file please?

Comment: where can i find the file?

Comment: I am still facing the problem.

Comment: There should be a build.gradle file in your app folder.